# how to pick answer/ bounty divide:ClassCastException in java?

Tags: discussion, site-usage

I have placed a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092141/what-else-can-throw-a-classcastexception-in-java). I plan to wait 2 more days but it looks like the only reason is different class loaders.

Can I give the bounty to 2 answers? Is there a link to a *How To*?

Keppil's answer was first and has the theory. Ed Plese has an example and he is new so want to reward him too.

Help me choose and let me know if I can give a bounty to both users? It would be nice to divide the bounty between them or give them both 50.

Comment: Just award the bounty to the one who deserves it most. And if you then still want to award a bounty, offer a new one (which has to be higher than the current one) and select the option to award it to an existing answer. OT: Could you please take care of proper capitalization at the very least?

Comment: okay Bart. your opinion on whose answer is better in this particular case?

Comment: You asked the question. You decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can award a bounty only to one answer. However if you want to award bounty to one more answer then you have to start one more bounty(offcourse, with higher value than current one) and award it to the other answer.

See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) and [privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) section for more details on bounty

Comment: your opinion on whose answer is better in this particular case?

Comment: @tgkprog you should award the bounty to one which really helped you. My opinion is to award bounty to Keppil's answer